# How to echo a coloured text in a textarea?

Tags: html, css

I am getting a problem while echoing a coloured text in a textarea.

Here is an example of what I did:

```
<?php   
$c='<span style="color:#0000FF;text-align:center;">Request has been sent. Please wait for my reply!</span>';
?>
<textarea align="CENTER" name="display_html" style="overflow:auto;resize:none" rows="5" cols="10"><?php echo $c; ?></textarea>
```

When running the script,the output in the textarea is: `<span style="color:#0000FF;text-align:center;">Request has been sent. Please wait for my reply!</span>`.

Why the "Request has been sent" is not being displayed in color in the textarea?

Comment: why not put this content in a div?

Comment: I used to put the `span` behind `textarea` using `CSS`, this way it looks like the text of `textarea` is colored.

Comment: Suppose i have 2 variables $a and $b which contains "hi" and "hello" respectively.i want to display $a in red and $b in blue color in the same textarea.

Comment: If you're trying to make some kind of chatbox or something, you will not be able to do what you want in a textarea. Use HTML divs.

Comment: You can use CSS `textarea { color:#000; }` single color only.

Comment: @scrowler am going for your suggested option :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You would need to use a Rich-Text Editor emulator like TinyMCE.

A bigger question is why are you trying to do that? That seems like the type of output that should just be within a div, not a textarea.

Comment: Can u please tell me how to use the TinyMCE ??

Comment: Google it, this website isn't for tutorials.

Comment: Am currenty doing this :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't put HTML content within a text area because it's displayed as it is (e.g. HTML source).
2. if you want to color **whole text** within the textarea you can try following code.

the css

```
.txtname
{
color:#0000FF;
}
<textarea align="CENTER" class="txtname" name="display_html" style="overflow:auto;resize:none" rows="5" cols="10">Request has been sent. Please wait for my reply!</textarea>
```

if you want **multiple colors** in textarea use rich text editor like [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)

```
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
</script>
```